# Realm Object Server - SSL configuration causes ROS to fail start

Tags: ssl, realm-mobile-platform

Ubuntu 16.04 / ROS v1.3.0

I am attempting to configure my ROS to use secure SSL connections.

If I do not make any changes to the `configuration.yml` - ROS is fine.  I can sync and use the dashboard as I would expect.

I have obtained an SSL cert from Letsencrypt.  I used the CertBot in standalone mode so that I did not have to install or configure Nginx.  (My preference is to not install yet another tech/layer - keep it clean!)

I have the following certificates/key stored in this folder:
`/etc/letsencrypt/live/data.mydomain.net/cert.pem`
`/etc/letsencrypt/live/data.mydomain.net/chain.pem`
`/etc/letsencrypt/live/data.mydomain.net/fullchain.pem`
`/etc/letsencrypt/live/data.mydomain.net/privkey.pem`

As soon as I enable HTTPS in the `configuration.yml` I am unable to launch ROS.

There are no error messages written to:
`/var/log/realm-object-server.log`

Here is a copy of the proxy section of `configuration.yml`.

```
  http:
    ## Whether or not to enable the HTTP proxy module. It enables multiplexing requests
    ## by forwarding incoming requests on a single port to all services.
    # enable: true

    ## The address/interface on which the HTTP proxy module should listen. This defaults
    ## to 127.0.0.1. If you wish to listen on all available interfaces,
    ## uncomment the following line.
    # listen_address: '::'

    ## The port that the HTTP proxy module should bind to.
    # listen_port: 9080

  https:
    ## Whether or not to enable the HTTPS proxy module. It enables multiplexing requests
    ## by forwarding incoming requests on a single port to all services.
    ## Note that even if it enabled, the HTTPS proxy will only start if supplied
    ## with a valid pair of certificates through certificate_path and private_key_path below.
    enable: true

    ## The path to the certificate and private keys (in PEM format) that will be used
    ## to set up the HTTPS server accepting connections.
    ## These configuration options are MANDATORY to start the HTTPS proxy module.
    certificate_path: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/data.mydomain.net/fullchain.pem'
    private_key_path: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/data.mydomain.net/privkey.pem'

    ## The address/interface on which the HTTPS proxy module should listen. This defaults
    ## to 127.0.0.1. If you wish to listen on all available interfaces,
    ## uncomment the following line.
    # listen_address: '::'

    ## The port that the HTTPS proxy module should bind to.
    listen_port: 9443
```

As I mention.  The issue appears to be that as soon as I configure HTTPS the ROS server fails to start.  If I disable the HTTPS then the ROS server starts without issue.

The reason I believe ROS is failing to start is - if I attempt `curl 127.0.0.1:9080` or `curl 127.0.0.1:9443` from the terminal I get the message `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9443: Connection refused`

I'd love to hear your ideas/thoughts/suggestions on how I can get this to work.  Cheers.  Ian

Comment: I forgot to add - If anyone has found/written a tutorial on how to configure ROS SSL please share the link!  Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  My system uses systemd and journalctl reveals a reason for ROS not starting: though pointed to the correct files, ROS fails on symlinks.  My solution was to use --renew-hook from certbot and copy the new cert files into /etc/realm/certs and pointing the configuration.yml to these files.  Now ROS starts again.

Comment: Thanks M-x.  I have tried your idea.  But no difference.  Please could I ask you to compare the settings I have (above) to yours?  I wonder if there is also some odd setting combination that breaks ROS.  Cheers.

Comment: @M-x.  I got it working.  Thanks to this question/answer.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952989/https-proxy-for-realm-object-server-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user @Radu - the answer was Permissions.

The `realm` user did not have permission to read the .pem files.

I picked up the answer from this answer.
[Https Proxy for Realm Object Server not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952989/https-proxy-for-realm-object-server-not-working)

@Radu - is the man!